# finding the vector coordinates with respect to basis $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

[image: Given]

I'm given this representation matrix of a linear operator in $\mathbb{R^4}$ , i'm trying to find the values of $a,b,c,d,e,f$.
Now to my understanding every column vector of the matrix is $[Tv_1]_B,[Tv_2]_B,[Tv_3]_B,[Tv_4]_B$.
i try to find the third column by $[Tv_3]_B=[T]_B*v3=(3,3,3,3)$ and then i try to find [Tv4]_B in the same way but i'm not comfortable with my answer because i get 
$[Tv_4]_B=[T]_B*v_4=(1,1,1,1)$ but the given vector $[Tv_4]_B$ starts with $4$ am i going at this wrong?

Comment: You cannot progress further without knowledge of $Tv_3 , Tv_4$

Comment: Strange because that is all that I'm given

Comment: How do you know that $[Tv_3] _B = (3,3,3,3)$?

Comment: I just multiplied v3 with the [T]_B matrix and got that vector

Comment: You can't do that, you need to multuiply $v_3$ representation in $B$

Comment: But isn't [T]_B the matrix representation of basis B?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58069/discussion-between-ofek-gillon-and-user3133165).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after clarification in the chat, I know that
$$ \dim \ker T =3 $$
the Rank–nullity theorem implies that
$$ \dim \operatorname{Im} T = 4- 3 = 1$$
Meaning that for every matrix representation,
$$ \dim \operatorname{rank} [T]_B =  1$$
And so there is only one vector in the basis of the space generated by the matrix's columns. One can see it is the vector $(1,1,1,1)^T$
Now you can understand that the missing columns are $(3,3,3,3) , (4,4,4,4)$